# Existe alguma especie de IFERROR no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Supondo o seguinte script:

```
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(100) = 'Stackoverflow';
DECLARE @var2 VARCHAR(100) = '10';
SELECT 1 * @var1;
SELECT 1 * @var2;
```

Se executar o primeiro `select`, receberemos um erro de:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Stackoverflow' to data
>   type int.

Se executarmos o segudo `select`, teremos sucesso. 
Minha pergunta é se existe alguma especie de tratamento - semelhante ao SEERRO do Excel - para utilizarmos no primeiro `select`, com isso teriamos algo do seguinte resultado:

```
SELECT IFERROR(1 * @var1, 'Erro', 'Sucesso')
```

Existe algo semelhante a isso no SQL Server? Eu pesquisei por algumas possibilidades, porém sempre vi a respeito de `rollback` e `transaction`, minha duvida é pra alguma função especifica.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Embora até tenha não é uma boa prática usar variáveis globais, pq vc não usa https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: ou simplesmente usa TRY CATCH https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia D. Watson.

Neste exemplo que você apresentou, está ocorrendo a conversão implícita entre um INT e um VARCHAR. Neste cenário, o SQL Server aplica as suas regras de precendência

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

> Quando um operador combinar duas expressões com tipos de dados
>   diferentes, o tipo de dados com a precedência mais baixa será
>   convertido no tipo de dados de maior precedência. Se a conversão não
>   for uma conversão implícita com suporte, será retornado um erro.

```
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(100) = 'Stackoverflow';
DECLARE @var2 VARCHAR(100) = '10';
SELECT 1 * @var1;
SELECT 1 * @var2;
```

Neste caso a precedência mais baixa é o VARCHAR que será convertida para INT.

Por isso da mensagem:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Stackoverflow' to data type int.
```

Abaixo as duas formas de prever esse tipo de erro, como foi muito bem exposto pelo JEAN nos links acima.

Utilizar o recurso de TRY CATCH

```
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(100) = 'Stackoverflow';
DECLARE @var2 VARCHAR(100) = '10';

BEGIN TRY 
   SELECT 1 * @var1;
   SELECT 1 * @var2;
   SELECT 'SUCESSO'
END TRY 
/*
*/
BEGIN CATCH 
    SELECT 'ERRO'
END CATCH
```

CASE com ISNUMERIC

```
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(100) = 'Stackoverflow';
DECLARE @var2 VARCHAR(100) = '10';

SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@VAR1) = 0 THEN 'ERRO' ELSE 'SUCESSO' END
```

Espero que ajude!!

Boa sorte .